# Specifying a type alias using CodeDom

Tags: c#, .net, codedom

I am dynamically generating some c# code using the CodeDom.  I want to ad a type alias  to the namespace.  Something like:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
   using Timer = System.Threading.Timer; 
   ...
}
```

I'm able to create the namespace but do not know how to create the type alias.  Code so far:

```
CodeCompileUnit unitCompile = new CodeCompileUnit();
CodeNamespace nsScript = new CodeNamespace("MyNamespace");
unitCompile.Namespaces.Add(nsScript);
```

How to add the "using Timer = System.Threading.Timer;" statement to the namespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly use in the `CodeNamespaceImport` class.

```
CodeNamespaceImport cd = 
    new CodeNamespaceImport("Timer = System.Threading.Timer");
```

It will generate classes like this.

```
using Timer = System.Threading.Timer;
```

I tried with VB.Net and it works. I didn't try with C#.